# Pug iteration -- express routes

Tags: express, iteration, pug

I have a route that returns error messages in express. Using connect-flash. Everything is working fine and I log the messages but I'm unable to display the messages in my pug file. Hopefully someone would direct me to my error/misunderstaning. I follow a tutorial to learn express, so I'll post my code first and then the tutorial code with handlebars.

My route is this:

```
    router.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
    var messages = req.flash('error')
    console.log(messages)
    res.render('signup', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), messages: messages, hasErrors : messages.length > 0 });
});
```

And here is my signup jade file. Notice the if block on top with "each" iteration and then displaying the SINGLE message in P line :

```
extends layout


block content

  //- The error is logged but not displaying in my pug
  //- Error iteration to display error messages
  if (hasErrors)
    each error in hasErrors
      p= error
  //- end of iteration
  div.constainer
    div.row
      div.col-md-4.offset-4
        h1 Signup
        form(action="" method="post")
          div.form-group
            label E-mail:
            br
            input.form-control( type="text" id="email" name="email")
          div.form-group
            label Password:
            br
          input.form-control( type="password" id="password" name="password")
          br
          input(type="hidden" name = "_csrf" value="#{csrfToken}")
        button(type="submit") Signup
```

The original tutorial has it with handlebars and it works. I'm trying to recreate the same example with pug. Here is the tutorial with handlebars code:

```
div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        >>>>>>***{{#if hasErrors}}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{# each messages }}
                    <p>{{this}}</p>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        >>>>>>{{/if}}***
        <form action="/user/signup" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{ csrfToken }}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code with handlebars code works. I just translated the same code to pug.
If I remove iteration completely and just add #{hasErrors} Jade display true and false so my route is fine, it is my iteration in Pug.

I'm a beginner. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try printing the `hasErrors`? It should be an array and not a boolean.

Comment: in my jade I just added #{hasErrors} and it compiled the page with "false" when I entered the user and password.

Comment: That is exactly what the problem is as `#{hasError}` simply has a flag of `true` or `false`, with which you are trying to loop in the next statement `each error in hasErrors`.
Either you should use another variable(array) or the `hasError` should be assigned with an array.

Comment: I used a tutorial to learn this and it is in handlebars, I'm just trying to create the same app in pug. I posted the handlebars code above and all I'm trying to do is to recreate the same app using pug. So it is not the route unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Now I see you have updated your question with the `handlebars` code. There you have wtitten `{{# each messages }}` and in Pug it is written as `each error in hasErrors`. Why is it not `each error in messages`?

Comment: Yes, that was a weird error on my part. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Alright, glad that I could help. I will mark it as an answer for the benefit of other users. You may choose it as the right answer and/or upvote it so that it will help the community. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by OP, the `each` statement should be `each error in messages`.